# SQL statement to join and give result in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, pivot

Can anyone help me with an sql statement to produce te following result?

```
Table Person
Person_ID  Name
1          John
2          Paul

Table Declaration
Decl_ID             Person_ID   Amount
1                   1               10
2                   2               12
3                   1               99
4                   1               24
```

Result of the SQL statment should look like this:

```
Name    Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
John    10      99      24
Paul    12
```

Comment: @user1788822 So if there are 1000000000000000000 records in `Declaration` for `John`, you would want 1000000000000000000 columns?

Comment: that looks like a pivot table, which standard sql is not suited for. that sort of transformation is best done client-side when you display the data.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the RDBMS, but this is basically a `pivot` if your database has access to that function.  If not, then you can replicate using a `case` and an aggregate function.

<strike>**MySQL**:</strike>

```
select name,
  sum(case when group_rn = 1 then amount else 0 end) Amount1,
  sum(case when group_rn = 2 then amount else 0 end) Amount2,
  sum(case when group_rn = 3 then amount else 0 end) Amount3
from
(
  select name,
    @num := if(@name = `name`, @num + 1, 1) as group_rn,
    @name := `name` as dummy,
    amount
  from
  (
    select p.name,
      d.amount,
      d.decl_id
    from person p
    inner join declaration d
      on p.person_id = d.person_id
  ) src
  order by name
) p
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f262/15)

In SQL Server and Oracle the `PIVOT` function exists:

**SQL Server**:

```
select name,
  [1] as Amount1,
  [2] as Amount2,
  [3] as Amount3
from
(
  select p.name,
    d.amount,
    row_number() over(partition by p.name order by d.amount) rn
  from person p
  inner join declaration d
    on p.person_id = d.person_id
) src
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920da/3)

You can create dynamic versions, in the event you have an unknown number of amounts that you want to turn into columns.

Edit, you stated you are using Oracle, so oracle specific answers are below:

**Oracle** 11g has the `pivot` function:

```
select name,
  Amount1,
  Amount2,
  Amount3
from
(
  select p.name,
    d.amount,
    row_number() over(partition by p.name order by d.amount) rn
  from person p
  inner join declaration d
    on p.person_id = d.person_id
) src
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for rn in ('1' as Amount1, '2' as Amount2, '3' as Amount3)
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/949b4/1)

If you are not on Oracle 11g, then you will need to use a `CASE` with aggregate function:

```
select name,
  sum(case when rn = 1 then amount else 0 end) Amount1,
  sum(case when rn = 2 then amount else 0 end) Amount2,
  sum(case when rn = 3 then amount else 0 end) Amount3
from
(
  select p.name,
    d.amount,
    row_number() over(partition by p.name order by d.amount) rn
  from person p
  inner join declaration d
    on p.person_id = d.person_id
) src
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/949b4/4)

Comment: Thanks!! Did not know that there was such a pivot function.

Comment: @user1788822 yes, both `oracle` and `sql server` have the `pivot` function.  It comes in handy for these types of results.  The `PIVOT` function only became available in 11g so it you are before that, then you will need to use a `case` with aggregate function.

Comment: @user1788822 are you going to have an unknown number of amount values that you need turned into columns?

Comment: No there is a maximum of 10 amounts, thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @user1788822 if any of the answers are helpful, be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left. It will help future visitors and you get reputation from accepting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a dynamic pivot.
The problem is that you need to execute your query as a string when you want a dynamic pivot.

Find the example: http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/05/generic-stored-procedure-for-pivot-in.html