# Efficiently Flattening a One To Many Relationship for Single Value Lookup in Key/Value Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a many to one relationship like the following:

**Activity Table**

| ActivityId | ActivityType | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***100*** | Account | 07/09/2021 |
| 200 | Account | 07/09/2021 |
| 300 | Book | 07/09/2021 |
| 400 | Book | 07/09/2021 |

**Activity Detail Table**

| ActivityId | ColumnId | NEWVALUE | OLDVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***100*** | AcctNbr | "123456" | "0123" |
| ***100*** | AcctName | "NewName" | "Old Name" |
| ***100*** | AcctRole | "Admin" | [NULL] |
| 400 | BookAdd | 123 | [NULL] |

I want to be able to answer the following question:

> How many AccountNumber Updates where there on 07/09/2021 and what are
> the (new) AccountNumbers that have been updated?

The solution I am imagining looks something like this:

| ActivityId | ActivityType | Timestamp | NewAcctNbr | NewAcctName | NewRole |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***100*** | Account | 07/09/2021 | "123456" | "NewName" | "Admin" |
| 400 | Book | 07/09/2021 | [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] |

---

Part of the reason I have been struggling to find resources to solve this problem is that I do not know what this type of relationship is called.

I would appreciate a concrete example of the SQL I would use in this situation, but it would also be fantastic if somebody could improve my vocabulary so I can more effectively research on my own.

Thank you

Comment: What does "updated" mean?

Comment: For context, these are Activities that Update an "entity" in the database. So the Activity with ID 100 was an update to an Activity where the "Name", "Role", and "AccountNbr" were updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity detail table is called a key/value table. I.e. it doesn't have one column per attribute (old_acoount, new_account, old_name, new_name, ...), but a key column (columnid) and a value column (two in fact: oldvalue and newvalue).

Key/value tables are not so easy to work with. Querying their data is usually done with conditional aggregation (a condition inside the aggregation function):

```
select
  a.activityid,
  a.activitytype,
  a.timestamp,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctNbr' then oldvalue end) as old_account,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctNbr' then newvalue end) as new_account,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctName' then oldvalue end) as old_name,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctName' then newvalue end) as new_name,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctRole' then oldvalue end) as old_role,
  max(case when columnid = 'AcctRole' then newvalue end) as new_role
from activity a
left join activity_detail ad on ad.activityid = a.activityid
where a.timestamp >= date '2021-09-07' and a.timestamp < date '2021-09-08'
group by a.activityid, a.activitytype, a.timestamp
order by a.activityid;
```

(We only want to group by activityid and show the activities' data. But Oracle requires that we group by activitytype and timestamp, too, although they are functionally dependent on the activityid. Oracle is not able to detect this, yet, so they don't comply with the SQL standard in this regard.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response and for the Oracle specific information.

Answer (score -1):

Below is something probably something you should take a look. You can use a pivot/case statement to accomplish what you need

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13160314/12176950