# Combine tables with pivot

Tags: sql

I have three different table with values, I got an output of first image but I want output as second Image.

**Query**

```
select HREmpParamValues.EmpParamID,HREmpParamValues.EmployeeId,HREmpParamValues.EntityTypeParamID,HREmpParamValues.ParamValue,
ORG_EntityTypeParam.ParamValueEntityID,ORG_EntityTypeParam.EntityTypeParamID,ORG_EntityTypeParam.Description,ORG_EntityTypeParam.DataTypeEntityID,ORG_EntityMaster.EntityId,ORG_EntityMaster.EntityTypeId,ORG_EntityMaster.Description
 from HREmpParamValues 
Left Join ORG_EntityTypeParam on ORG_EntityTypeParam.EntityTypeParamID =  HREmpParamValues .EntityTypeParamID
Left Join ORG_EntityMaster on ORG_EntityMaster.EntityId = HREmpParamValues.ParamValueEntityID
where HREmpParamValues.EmployeeId=31
```

**Output**
[image]

**Desired Output**
[image]

Comment: Ah, one of those annoying key/value tables. They are usually queried with conditional aggregation. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320457/efficiently-flattening-a-one-to-many-relationship-for-single-value-lookup

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)